# Foreign keys query

Tags: database, foreign-keys

[image]

---

I understand the first two foreign keys. **Consult** is getting **did** from **Doctor** and **nhi** from **Patient** because they are keys from other tables. However, I don't understand the last two foreign keys, I have no idea what they mean. Would some one be able to help me understand., maybe by giving an English description of what exactly is going on?

Comment: It would be helpful to you if would quote the textbook's *definition* of FK. And if you read it carefully.

Comment: Just edited my answer to find it accepted and upvoted... hope it is still clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that there is a foreign key (FK) from one table's columns to anothers' is to say that

- Every subrow value for the columns of the first appears as a subrow value for the columns of the second. Ie there is an inclusion dependency (IND) from those columns of the first to those columns of the second.
- Every subrow value for the columns of the second is unique in its table and contains no subrow that is unique in its table. Ie that those columns form a key in their table.

(The columns of the first table do not have to have the same names as the columns in the second table. If there are multiple columns then the order in a list is usually used to say what first table column references what second table column.)

So a FK is really a constraint or condition. It is either satisfied by (is true of) (holds for) given tables or not. (Your question's "they are keys from other tables" is so sloppy that it isn't helping you understand.)

What a table means (some sentence parameterized by its columns) determines its value (the rows that satisfy (ie are true of) (ie hold for)) a given application situation. Eg Consult holds the rows where:

```
patient [nhi] consulted doctor [did] on [date] with diagnosis [diagnosis]
```

Lets's check whether each foreign key (constraint/condition) is satisfied by (ie is true of) (ie holds for) the particular table values you gave for Consult and Patient:

1 Consult did references Doctor did TRUE because every Consult did *is* some Doctor did value

2 Consult nhi references Patient nhi TRUE because every Consult nhi *is* some Patient nhi value

3 Consult nhi references Doctor did TRUE because every Consult nhi *is* some Doctor did value

4 Consult did references Patient nhi TRUE because every Consult did *is* some Patient nhi value

**ps**

We tell the DBMS that that some given FK is satisfied by every database state. So the DBMS disallows states that don't satisfy the FK. (They are errors.) The declaration creates a name-FK pair called a DBMS constraint with a given FK and (possibly default/implicit) name. So alas "FK" and "constraint" get used to mean both DBMS constraint (name-FK pair) and the FK of one.

In a database with those tables and meanings every state will satisfy FKs 1 and 2 so we would declare them to the DBMS. Not every state will satisfy 3 and 4 so we would not. We would say "there are FKs 1 and 2" and "3 and 4 are not FKs" in that database. But that is a sloppy way of saying that the database satisfies 1 and 2 but not 3 and 4 or that we declared 1 and 2 but not 3 or 4.

**pps**

A FK can be phrased in terms of table meanings. Suppose table T1 is the rows where T1(c1,...,x1,....) and T2 is the rows where T2(c2,...,x2,...). Then the FK that

```
T1 (c1,...) references T2 (c2,...)
```

is the FK that

```
EXISTS x1,... T1(c1,...,x1,....) IMPLIES EXISTS x2,... T2(c2,...,x2,...)
```

Eg if Consult(nhi,did,date,diagnosis) (ie patient [nhi] consulted doctor [did] on date [date] with diagnosis [diagnosis]) for some did, date and diagnosis then Patient(nhi,pname,bday) (ie patient [nhd] named [pname] was born on [bday]) for some pname and bday. Ie if nhi consulted a doctor then nhi is a patient.